# Google play: missing information in prominent disclosure

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I've filled google play support disagreement form about their decision of "missing information in prominent disclosure". But they answered me with basically the same response they gave me in app review:

> Specifically, missing information in prominent disclosure.
>
> Your prominent disclosure must appear before your app’s location
> runtime permission, and should tell the user which feature(s) will use
> location in the background. Based on our review, your app’s prominent
> disclosure did not include the term “location” / indication that the
> nature of usage is in the background by using one of the following
> phrases “background” / “when the app is closed” / “always in use” /
> “when the app is not in use” / a list of all the features that use
> location in the background / one of the following phrases “used to
> provide ads/support advertising/support ads” (if you extend permitted
> usage to ads).

---

My current disclosure string which I display inside dialog before runtime permission dialog with buttons **Turn on** and **Reject**:

```
This app collects background location data even when the app is closed, to enable:
    \n - distance calculation between courier and restaurant or client
    \n - restrict order assignment and delivery based on that distance
```

- Includes term “location”
- Includes one of the following phrases    “background” / “when the app
  is closed” / “always in use” / “when the    app is not in use” /
- Lists all the features that use location in the background
- I don’tuse location in ads.

Please let me know what is wrong because I'm mad already as I don't see any discrepancies.

Comment: Did you get to solve it? We are having the same issue!

Comment: No, I didn't. I just hosted app on private server and made an auto update check in json file using this library https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater . I bet google doesn't like this constant check of location every 15s :)

Comment: So basically you're hosting your app from your private server, not google play store? Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: But the AppUpdater you mentioned doesn't provide feature to update app by itself. How did you implement updating?

Comment: Just download and update .apk file on top of existing. There are other 3rd party updater libraries on github that can update app without leaving the app :)

Answer (score 1):

I also had a same problem. I refer the [Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-provide-prominent-in-app-disclosure%2Ccan-i-publish-app-updates-while-still-working-on-location-compliance%2Capp-review-considerations%2Csee-an-example-of-prominent-in-app-disclosure) and written the description as below. My app got approved.

> **My Taxi App collects location data to enable below features even when the app is closed or not in use.**
>
> 1. **To provide the nearest jobs**
> 2. **Allows the customer to track the driver, when his/her driver is on the way to pickup.**
> 3. **Increase the efficiency and smoothness of the trip.**
>
> **When you allow background location, it will give you more earnings.**

I hope this may help other developers.

**Other example from Play Console Help**

[image]

Comment: Which permission it is that allowing user to allow location permission all time